# Regex to extract block of data

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Would somebody care to help me out with a `preg_match_all` Regex?

I need to extract from a block that looks like this:

```
(arbitrary data)
alt=BAUSTEIN^550^^transparent^transparent^null^null^(...base64 encoded data...) ^
(arbitrary data)
alt=BAUSTEIN^550^^transparent^transparent^null^null^(...base64 encoded data...) ^
```

all base64 encoded blocks. The rule is: There is always `alt=BAUSTEIN` followed by six columns of arbitrary data delimited by `^`. The base64 encoded column is also delimited by `^`

my current feeble attempt contains a lot of `([^\^].*)` and won't match anything. Pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your example very well, but would this do it?

```
alt=BAUSTEIN\^+(.+?)\^+(.+?)\^+(.+?)\^+(.+?)\^+(.+?)\^+(.+?)\^+
```

Or a more refined one:

```
^alt=BAUSTEIN\^+(.+?)\^+(.+?)\^+(.+?)\^+(.+?)\^+(.+?)\^+([0-9a-zA-Z+/=]+)\^+$
```

Comment: No problem, but Ruben solution is much more simpler: `alt=BAUSTEIN(?:\^.*?){6}\^(.*?)\^`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
alt=BAUSTEIN(?:\^.*?){6}\^(?<base64>.*?)\^
```

Comment: Cheers Rubens, I found this regex the most elegant but somehow I couldn't get it to work, I don't know why. The first bracketed expression is beatiful, though, something to keep in mind.

Comment: @Pekka: It's probably the .Net named capture (`?<base64>`).

Comment: you're right, @Alix; you can to strip that `?<base64>` if you want, but I just read php >= 5.2.2 supports it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Nope, I stripped the base64 and replaced it by `(.*?)` (good to know that it's a valid expression though, thanks!) Still doesn't match (the result is empty).  Strange, I can't see why.

Answer (score 1):

here's one way without regex. since you have distinct delimiters, you can use splitting approach.

```
$str= <<<A
(arbitrary data)
alt=BAUSTEIN^550^^transparent^transparent^null^null^(...base64 encoded data...) ^
(arbitrary data)
alt=BAUSTEIN^550^^transparent^transparent^null^null^(...base64 encoded data...)
A;

$s = explode("^",$str);
for($i=0;$i<count($s);$i++){
    #check for alt=BAUSTEIN , if yes, go 6 indices forward to get your stuff
    if ( strpos($s[$i] ,"alt=BAUSTEIN" ) !==FALSE){
        print $s[$i+7]."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers Ghostdog, a regex did it for me nicely in this case but this is definitely a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$regex ="@^alt=@BAUSTEIN\^{2}[a-zA-Z]{1}\^[a-zA-Z]{1}\^(.*)"
```

Comment: "six columns of arbitrary data"; a 0 in any will break your regex